How do I customise the button image in a menu item?
I’m working on a macOS application, and I need to use a menu.
I can customise the font size and colour of the text of the menu item buttons, but I can’t see how to make a difference with the image in the buttons.
Here is some sample code:
Button(action: { print("Something") }) {
    HStack {
        Image(systemName: "questionmark.circle")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
        Text("Something")
            .font(.system(size: 24))
    }
}
Menu("☰") {
    Button(action: { print("Something") }) {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "questionmark.circle")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
            Text("Something")
                .font(.system(size: 24))
        }
    }
    Button(action: { print("Something Else") }) {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.circle")
            Text("Something Else")
                .font(.system(size: 32))
        }
    }
}
.menuStyle(.button)
.buttonStyle(.plain)

I’ve included a styled button before the menu to illustrate that I can make changes to the button, but those changes don’t work for the buttons inside the menu:

How can I make changes to the button images in the menu items?

I don’t imagine the downvoter would care to share what’s wrong with the question?

One way to solve is to create an image from the symbol, using the size of your choice. The answer to How do I put an icon into a toolbar menu and have it correctly sized can be adapted for this (it was my answer):
struct ResizedSymbol: View {
    let systemName: String
    var targetSize: CGFloat = 20

    var body: some View {
        let size = CGSize(width: targetSize, height: targetSize)
        let image = Image(systemName: systemName)
        return Image(size: size) { ctx in
            let resolvedImage = ctx.resolve(image)
            let imageSize = resolvedImage.size
            let maxDimension = min(imageSize.width, imageSize.height)
            let w = targetSize * imageSize.width / max(1, maxDimension)
            let h = targetSize * imageSize.height / max(1, maxDimension)
            let x = (targetSize - w) / 2
            let y = (targetSize - h) / 2
            ctx.draw(resolvedImage, in: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: w, height: h))
        }
    }
}

HStack {
    ResizedSymbol(systemName: "questionmark.circle", targetSize: 24)
        .foregroundColor(.blue)
    Text("Something")
        .font(.system(size: 24))
}

HStack {
    ResizedSymbol(systemName: "exclamationmark.circle", targetSize: 32)
    Text("Something Else")
        .font(.system(size: 32))
}


